# java - is there a way to confirm that a string is a sha256 hash?

Tags: java, sha

I'd like to validate that a String is a sha256 representation of another without  having to decrypt it. Is this possible?

Comment: A hash isn't encryption. It's very unclear what you're asking at the moment. Basically the way to validate the hash is to re-hash the string, and see whether you get the same hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sha-256 value is just a 256 bits (32 bytes) value which you usually represent as a `String` or as a `byte[]` in Java.

As a value per se it's pointless, if you want to tell if a specific `String` is a hash then any 32 bytes number is a hash of an infinite unknown plain texts. But it's like asking "how do I know that a 32 bytes number is a number?", you see that you are going nowhere.

It's useful only when it's paired to a plain text so that you can compare it with the hash computed from the plain text to verify they match.

Comment: "*any 32 bytes number is a hash of an infinite unknown plain texts*" => are there really 2^32 possible SHA256 values?

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2670/is-every-output-of-a-hash-function-possible

Comment: @assylias: probably you meant `2^(32*8)` possible SHA256 values but in general your question doesn't have an answer, as it's specific to the hash function involved. Assuming an infinite possible amount of plain texts of any possible length then the codomain of the hash function could be complete if the function itself is well suited. Proving it is a different story.

Comment: Yes 2^256 of course. My point was that there is no (practical) way to say if a random 32 byte value can be obtained by sha256-ing some string. Which is the question asked I think.

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no.

You can test that a string is hex very easily. You can then test that it contains a statistically sensible number of digits and letters. That will rule out some common non sha256 strings.

But if someone creates a random string designed to look like a sha256, I don't think it's possible to distinguish it from the real thing by any mathematical test. The algorithm is designed to be robust to that.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you could do is to hash the other string and then compare these two strings with each other.
No idea if this would help you but I read that it was commonly used praxis when creating rainbow tables for cracking password attempts.
EDIT: Oh forgot this is also the way to compare passwords in php when you login to a webpage iirc.
 At least I had to do it like this for university.

Comment: This would not work, since you do not know the hash being used by the two values is the same.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but since OP said it was a sha2 hash, there should be a standard function of hashing it, like the md5 function in php.